# How to force a Set object to contain all values within an enum - TS

Tags: typescript, enums, set

I have the following enum:

`enum GREETINGS { HELLO = 'Hello', HI = 'Hi' }`

I want to create a type for a Set data structure which would force the user to include all of the enum values within it, like below:

`type MyGreetings = Set<GREETINGS>`

The expected outcome should cause the following line to be highlighted with a warning stating that not all required values are included within the result:

`const result: MyGreetings = new Set([GREETINGS.HELLO]);`

Comment: TypeScript doesn't work that way: it cannot enforce that a `Set` will have certain members... only that members must be of a certain type. I have a feeling that a `Set` is not the appropriate data structure for this scenario. ([`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on arrays might be of interest to you.) Can you tell us more about your real objective: What are you ultimately trying to achieve using this compile-time "type guard"?

Comment: I use Sets quite heavily within my projects as they are the most appropriate data structure for simplistic use cases of checking whether a value exists. I have no problem in utilising other data structures to fit the use case described in my question, however I wanted to double check if TypeScript can be used to create these kinds of constrains for Sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is that TypeScript considers `Set<GREETINGS.HELLO>` to be [assignable to / compatible with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) `Set<GREETINGS>`; in theory that should mean that if you want `Set<GREETINGS>` to be assignable to `MyGreetings`, then by [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) of assignability,  `Set<GREETINGS.HELLO>` will also be assignable to `MyGreetings`, and you're stopped before you've begun.  But:

The fact that `Set<GREETINGS.HELLO>` is assignable to `Set<GREETINGS>` is actually using an intentional hole in the type system: [method parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance).   Method parameter bivariance is very useful, but it is not type safe:

```
const justHello = new Set<GREETINGS.HELLO>([GREETINGS.HELLO]);
const stillJustHello: Set<GREETINGS> = justHello;
stillJustHello.add(GREETINGS.HI) // <-- no error, oops
```

By "widening" `justHello` to `stillJustHello`, the compiler has forgotten that it should not accept any member but `GREETINGS.HELLO`.

So one way to get closer to what you want is to use [the `--strictFunctionType` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes) (which is part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) and is recommended in general) and rewrite at least one `Set` method signature using a [*function* property type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#arrow-functions) instead of a method signature.  Let's look at `add()` and see the difference:

```
type Method = { add(x: GREETINGS): void } // method syntax
const m: Method = new Set<GREETINGS.HELLO>(); // okay

type FuncProp = { add: (x: GREETINGS) => void } // function syntax
const f: FuncProp = new Set<GREETINGS.HELLO>(); // error
```

---

So let's try something like:

```
type MyGreetings = Set<GREETINGS> & { add: (g: GREETINGS) => MyGreetings };
```

If we use that, you get the desired result:

```
const result: MyGreetings = new Set([GREETINGS.HELLO]); // error!
//  Type 'GREETINGS' is not assignable to type 'GREETINGS.HELLO'

const okay: MyGreetings = new Set([GREETINGS.HELLO, GREETINGS.HI]); // okay
```

Hooray!

---

Well, kind of.  The compiler really cannot know exactly *which* values have been passed into a `Set`.  It can *infer* that `new Set(...)` is of type `Set<X>` for some `X`, but there are ways to manually specify a wider `X` or get the compiler to infer a wider `X`.  And then all the progress from above is lost.

For example, since a `Set<GREETINGS>` is allowed to contain just a subset of `GREETINGS`, someone can do the following manual specification:

```
const oops: MyGreetings = new Set<GREETINGS>([GREETINGS.HELLO]) // no error
```

Or someone could get the compiler to infer a union this way:

```
const alsoOops: MyGreetings = new Set([
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? GREETINGS.HELLO : GREETINGS.HI
]); // no error
```

Neither of those can be an error; the value on the right hand side of the equals sign is a `Set<GREETINGS>`.  And you need `Set<GREETINGS>` to be assignable to `MyGreetings`, so the assignments are also not errors.  There's not much that can be done about this.

If in practice you don't think someone will create a set in these or other pathological ways, then maybe you can use `MyGreetings`.  Otherwise, if you really need to guarantee something, you should consider changing your design in some way.  But this is probably out of scope for the question, so I'll stop there.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA4gSgUQQFQJIDkYGUoG8oASCAMsQPJQC8UA5AcADYMD2NANIalbQQJY1QAvgChhAY2YgAzgBcoAKzCz6TZtxDAA7lCzAZAHnhI0mLADoipMgD4AFAG0jKDNgslyAXQCUAbmGLlRhYzAEMAEzDbJxNXAlQvKAB6RKh9AFo0qGAAJ2zmbI5mADMoCTBsqWBRCWk5WV4mACklGRUWAC4dPUNEZ1NrbgDWoOY-eqaWtuZQiKjemPM4hOTUjKgQNRy87PXmTULmAAcpURkAT0PgKABZPQALZjDufHDIgA9O6JcsL06AN2YvCeIhqsigEE6txkDye1A02l0Bi+pjcVjsviSKWYAGsQmdThcrgAxMAgMQABTyh2eUFenVsH1g82+CUoAwBQKE4kkYKKnRJZMpR3UWi6SOZKMs5HRPkxWVy+VESvOlxuZxg2WAel4IAA5lJuIiesZvgMAGR4WkRem6z4S7CsgbXdWa7V6g2CPzc2pQTVSMAMGSQl1amQ6-UihF6BzI2LuMjeWUrLb5ACEwhWUGQhNosawAl4Bo2chCUikvF1IBCACMGFcZGoVVcaHnUeQaNUeXIcXjgxrQ+GDXDRYiY-bFvGOK24om5T38d6wcwjlI+66w+7I2LjX1sHZHOO2wnlikNvLtp2fSEGFJmGQV2uB5vh1GZA5riFoWZsiEQGFmBAtgJPoUAAAxmAArFAAD8TImpK8ZQHa8GxKgs4rGeKbZKIQA) (tested and working for typescript version 3.5.1 and higher)

Comment: I don't understand why but this just does not work for me as copied and pasted. `result` does not generate any error for me.

Comment: I don't understand why either, given that the Playground link in the answer, using the current version of TS (4.7.4 as of today) clearly shows the error.  Perhaps there something idiosyncratic about your configuration?  Are you not using `--strict`?  Is there something I should do here to earn the retraction of a downvote?

Comment: I've tried and failed to get the version of ts that my checker is using (which I previously assumed to be current), but I've been able to reproduce the... error? lack thereof? on the Playground by setting the version to 3.3.3 so I'll just eat my frustration and blame it on an old version of typescript for now. I'll add that to your answer and remove the downvote.